# "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials" during running dataflow

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read data from the external bigquery table (i.e. linked to google sheet) in apache beam pipeline as below and later loading into bigquery table only.

But the code getting failed with below error during reading data,

**Error:** "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials."

**dataflow Code:**

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=google_cloud_options) as p:
            # Step 1: Get URL list from BigQuery table
            urls = (
                p | 'Get URLs from BQ Table' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                    query="""
                        SELECT cast(id as INT64) AS site_id, url
                        FROM `my-project.my_dashboard.MAP_URLS_GSHEET`
                    """,
                    use_standard_sql=True
                )
            )
```

Could you please help here , how to solve this issue i.e. specially when running through dataflow?

Comment: A quick google search found this and it might be helpful. Try checking your account permissions, https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/troubleshooting/access-gdrive-credential#:~:text=Usually%20this%20errors%20indicates%20that,Google%20Drive%20or%20Google%20Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add BigQuery permissions to the service account being used on the Dataflow job / workers.

Please check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#worker-service-account for more information.

Comment: I have added the bigquery permission to the service account used for the Dataflow job. If I use the native BQ table, then the dataflow is successfully reading and loading data into BQ. But when I am using external table as mentioned in the query , getting the same error. So don't know how to access the google sheet linked to external BQ table from Dataflow job.